# how to populate SLDS date value in edit mode using javascript

Tags: visualforce, javascript-remoting, slds

I have a date field

```
<div class="slds-form-element">
    <label class="slds-form-element__label">Date of Birth</label>
    <div class="slds-form-element__control">
        <input id="EmpDOBId" type="date" class="slds-input" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I am getting object.dob__c = 86400000  // millisecond value

i want to populate this in the above filed. I have written the below code.

```
 document.getElementById('EmpDOBId').innerHTML = new Date(object.dob__c);
```

or

```
 document.getElementById('EmpDOBId').value = new Date(object.dob__c);
```

but it is not populating the value. can someone help me? thanks in advance.

Comment: What context are we in? Lightning/LEX? SF1? Visualforce? Some other server (i.e. plain HTML)?

Comment: Visualforce. but i am using SLDS for UI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a working example, cannibalize a needed, not sure if there is a better way or not:

```
<apex:page id="myTestPage">
    <apex:slds />

    <div class="slds-form-element">
        <label class="slds-form-element__label">Date of Birth</label>
        <div class="slds-form-element__control">
            <input id="EmpDOBId" type="date" class="slds-input" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.getElementById('EmpDOBId').value = formatDate(new Date(86400000));

        function formatDate(date) {
            var d = new Date(date),
                    month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
                    day = '' + d.getDate(),
                    year = d.getFullYear();

            if (month.length < 2) month = '0' + month;
            if (day.length < 2) day = '0' + day;

            return [year, month, day].join('-');
        }
    </script>
</apex:page>
```

You need to set the `value` of the input not the `innerHTML`. The format of the value is `yyyy-mm-dd`

I do not believe there is a native formater for the javascript date object but I am no Js expert either

Adapted from answer [Format JavaScript Date to yyyy-mm-dd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23593052/format-javascript-date-to-yyyy-mm-dd)